# jackson serialization with recursive structure

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, jackson

I have this java model serialized by jackson:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="orderId")
public class ClonedOrder extends ResourceSupport implements Serializable{
    private long orderId;
    private ClonedOrder parent;
    private List<ClonedOrder> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("root")
    public ClonedOrder root() {
        if (parent == null) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return parent.root();
        }
    }
```

When jackson serialize this tree the response is as following:

```
{
  "orderId": 163811134,
  "parent": {
    "orderId": 153684020,
    "parent": null,
    "children": [],
    "root": 153684020
  },
  "children": [
   {
     "orderId": 163811135,
     "parent": 163811134,
     "children": [],
     "root": 153684020
   },
  "root": 153684020
}
```

The problem is that the root node that is of type ClonedOrder is not serialized as a ClonedOrder (with parent, children and root) but only with the id as long type.

The problem is that I cannot use the same model for serialize and deserialize since the json changes from server to client.

Any idea how to achieve this goal?

Comment: JSON can only contain values; the format does not have any definition for referencing an object. JSON can not handle representing cycles in your object references. You need to design your API and JSON model with those constraints in mind and write your client and your server code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed before, with `JsonIdentityInfo` jackson just serialises the `long orderId` and it skips the standard java-object serialisation to avoid infinite nested objects (means stackoverflow).

I suggest to serialise all the data you need with a simpler data structure like the model you would use to store these data in a relational database. The model I am figuring out is this:

```
relations: [
    {"id": 163811134, "parent": 153684020},
    {"id": 163811135, "parent": 163811134},
    {"id": 153684020, "parent": null},
]
```

with this structure it is very simple to find what you needed using utility methods:

```
private class CloningRelations {
    List<CloningOrder> orders;

    public Long getRoot(){
        for (CloningOrder o : orders)
            if (o.getParent() != null)
                return o.getId();
        return null;
    }

    @JsonIgnore public List<Long> getChildrenOf(long id) {
        ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CloningOrder o : orders)
            if (o.getParent() == id)
                list.add(o.getId());
        return list;
    }

    @JsonIgnore public List<Long> getDescendantsOf(long id) {
        ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CloningOrder o : orders)
            if (o.getParent() == id) {
                list.add(o.getId());
                list.addAll(getDescendantsOf(o.getId()));
            }
        return list;
    }

    @JsonIgnore public Long getParentOf(long id) {
        for (CloningOrder o : orders)
            if (o.getId() == id)
                return o.getParent();
        return null;
    }

    @JsonIgnore public List<Long> getAncestorsOf(long id) {
        ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CloningOrder o : orders)
            if (o.getId() == id) {
                list.add(o.getParent()); //sorted too!
                list.addAll(getAncestorsOf(o.getParent()));
            }
        return list;
    }

    private class CloningOrder {
        long id;
        Long parent;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Long getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void setParent(Long parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two annotations `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to handle bi-directional references.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#object-references-identity)